# How to setup two dynamic conditions in SUMIFS like problem in R?

Tags: r, dynamic, conditional-statements, sumifs

I already tried my best but am still pretty much a newbie to R.

Based on like 500mb of **input** data that currently looks like this:

```
TOTALLISTINGS
  listing_id calc.latitude calc.longitude reviews_last30days
1       2818       5829821       335511.0                  1
2      20168       5829746       335265.2                  3
3      25428       5830640       331534.6                  0
4      27886       5832156       332003.1                  3
5      28658       5830888       329727.2                  3
6      28871       5829980       332071.3                  7
```

I need to calculate the conditional sum of `reviews_last30days` - the conditions being a specific and changing area range for each respective record, i.e. R should sum only those reviews for which the `calc.latitude` and `calc.longitude` do not deviate more than +/-500 from the longitude and latitude values in each row.

**EXAMPLE:**

- ROW 1 has a `calc.latitude` 5829821 and a `calc.longitude` 335511.0, so R should take the sum of all `reviews_last30days` for which the following ranges apply: `calc.latitude` 5829321‬ to 5830321‬ (value of Row 1 latitude +/-500)
  `calc.longitude` 335011.0 to 336011.0 (value of Row 1 longitude +/-500)

So my intended **output** would look somewhat like this in column 5:

```
TOTALLISTINGS
 listing_id calc.latitude calc.longitude reviews_last30days  reviewsper1000
1       2818       5829821       335511.0                  1             4
2      20168       5829746       335265.2                  3             4
3      25428       5830640       331534.6                  0            10
4      27886       5832156       332003.1                  3             3
5      28658       5830888       331727.2                  3            10
6      28871       5829980       332071.3                  7            10
```

*Hope I calculated correctly in my head, but you get the idea..*

Until now I particularly struggle with the fact that my sum conditions are dynamic and "newly assigned" since the latitude and longitude conditions have to be adjusted for each record.

My current code looks like this but it obviously doesn't work that way:

```
review1000 <- function(TOTALLISTINGS = NULL){
      # tibble to return
      to_return <- TOTALLISTINGS %>% 
        group_by(listing_id) %>% 
        summarise(
          reviews1000 = sum(reviews_last30days[(calc.latitude>=(calc.latitude-500) | calc.latitude<=(calc.latitude+500))]))
      return(to_return)
    }

REVIEWPERAREA <- review1000(TOTALLISTINGS)
```

*I know I also would have to add something for longitude in the code above*

Does anyone have an idea how to fix this? 
Any help or hints highly appreciated & thanks in advance! :)

Comment: What you mean by _from the respective coordinates._ also if you can tell how you got 4,4,10 etc in `reviewsper1000`

Comment: Both `calc.latitude>=(calc.latitude-500)` and `calc.latitude<=(calc.latitude+500)` are **always** true.

Comment: I think you need to try to explain again what you are trying to do. As I don't think we understand sufficiently to be able to help. E.g. Do you mean you need to sum all the listing_ids and their review tallies with lat and long within 500 of each other?

Comment: By *from the respective coordinates* I mean, e.g. that for the first record, the deviation of longitude (in this case: 528981) and latitude (335511.0) must not > than +/- 500. This condition should then be adjustable to each respective record. Calculation of ```reviewsper1000```: E.g. for the record in [1,5] I calculated how many of ```reviews_last30days``` fulfil the criteria mentioned above, resulting in 1 from [1,4] + 3 from [2,4] = 4

Comment: Pleas edit the question to make this clear. I'm sure you'll get an answer then.

Comment: I just added an example to my question describing the calculation I would require -hope that helps!

Comment: @giannis.mvp I didn't get the exact number as yours but you can start with `lapply(1:nrow(df), function(x){
  #browser()
  rw <- df[x,]
  rw$reviewsper1000 <- filter(df,between(calc.latitude,rw$calc.latitude-500,rw$calc.latitude+500) & between(calc.longitude,rw$calc.longitude-500,rw$calc.longitude+500)) %>% pull(reviews_last30days) %>% sum()
  
  return(rw)
})`, latter change lapply to `map_df` to get a df.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See whether the below code will help.

```
TOTALLISTINGS$reviews1000 <- sapply(1:nrow(TOTALLISTINGS), function(r) {
  currentLATI <- TOTALLISTINGS$calc.latitude[r]
  currentLONG <- TOTALLISTINGS$calc.longitude[r]
  sum(TOTALLISTINGS$reviews_last30days[between(TOTALLISTINGS$calc.latitude,currentLATI - 500, currentLATI + 500) & between(TOTALLISTINGS$calc.longitude,currentLONG - 500, currentLONG + 500)])
})
```